# How to push my own DNS server to OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, dns-server

I have defined an [unbound](https://calomel.org/unbound_dns.html) DNS server on my VPS and it appears to work. I need to use the DNS server instead of public DNS servers because some ISPs have blocked public DNS IPs. My openvpn.conf file is:

```
    dev tun
    proto tcp

    # Notice: here I set the listening port to be 80 to avoid possible port blockage
    port 80

    ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
    cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
    key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
    dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem

    user nobody
    group nogroup
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

    persist-key
    persist-tun

    #status openvpn-status.log
    #verb 3
    client-to-client

    push "redirect-gateway def1"

    #pushing public DNS IPs

    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.220"

    comp-lzo
```

As it is suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/117836/openvpn-and-dns-how-to), I tried to use my server's IPs (say 11.22.33.44). So instead of

```
    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.220"
```

I just put

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 11.22.33.44"
```

In openvpn.conf above. However, after restarting openvpn, I see that my client can still connect to the OpenVPN server but no pages can be rendered anymore.

What can be wrong here? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's an old question, but to test "push 'dhcp-option DNS 11.22.33.44"' I'd try another Internet DNS server (e.g. Google's 8.8.8.8) to determine if "dhcp-option DNS" is working.  I suspect it will be, and you'll need to debug (perhaps with tracert) how and why it isn't working as a DNS server for you  Perhaps firewall?

Answer (score 40):

On `Windows 10` clients, you need add the following directives to `client.ovpn`:

```
script-security 2                                                                                                       
dhcp-option DNS 10.0.8.1                                                                                           
dhcp-option DOMAIN example.lan
```

> No more directives are required for windows.

On `Ubuntu 16.04` clients, you may need add following directives to `client.ovpn`:

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf                                                                                      
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

The latest OpenVPN client versions for Windows do not recognize option `DOMAIN-SEARCH` correctly, and work with `DOMAIN`.

Comment: Does this require a particular minimum OpenVPN version?

Comment: I think you should use the VPN gateway IP (10.0.8.1), not the router's local gateway ip address (192.168.1.1). That's such a common router ip address that likely the untrusted network router they're directly connected to will be at the 192.168.1.1 address.

Comment: I tried it on my mac - it was ignored because my profile is untrusted, what should I do

Answer (score 10):

You say that the "it appears to work." How did you verify this? Are you basing it on the fact the server started without any errors or did you actually perform some queries against it?

First thing I would do is use nslookup or dig to connect to the unbound server and perform some queries.  I know dig is more in fashion these days but I know nslookup better.

```
$ nslookup
> server 11.22.33.44
Default server: 11.22.33.44
Address: 11.22.33.44#53
> set type=A
> www.google.com
Server:     11.22.33.44
Address:    11.22.33.44#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.google.com  canonical name = www.l.google.com.
Name:   www.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.225.52
Name:   www.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.225.48
Name:   www.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.225.49
Name:   www.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.225.50
Name:   www.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.225.51
```

If this does not work then you have to look back at the DNS configuration again.

Is this a primary DNS server or a caching DNS server? Are you trying to query local resources or internet resources? Does it work as expected if you do not push your DNS server to the client?

If you pass all your traffic through your OpenVPN server you should not need to worry about your ISP blocking public DNS servers anymore since as far as your ISP is concerned you are only generating traffic to your VPS; unless the VPS is behind the same ISP.

Comment: Well ubound could pass all the tests that you mentioned and some more so I'm pretty sure that it is not the problem. As for why I need to use my own DNS server, I have experienced that when I use public DNS as above, the clients in Iran (where millions of sites are blocked) can not get any page through their openvpn connection, despite the fact that they can connect to the openvpn server. Hence the effort. Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that they can get a webpage via IP address once they are connected? This would just make sure it really is DNS problem and not a routing issue. Its very common when setting up OpenVPN to be able to connect to the server but not get any traffic back due to a missing return route.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that if you are trying to connect from a non-Windows client, you need to do a couple of extra steps:

**On Linux**

Put this line on your client configuration (`client.conf` or `xxxx.ovpn`file)

```
dhcp-option DNS 11.22.33.44
```

Call the OpenVPN client in this way:

```
$ openvpn --script-security 2 --config xxxx.ovpn
```

That worked for me.

Comment: `Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: script-security`

Answer (score 1):

> Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 at 13 Sep 2018

There is another useful commands to setup what you need via command line. But in my case you can control your VPN connection both with command line and GUI.

`sudo nmcli connection add type vpn vpn-type openvpn con-name la.vpn.contoso.com ifname --`

> `ifname --` is the required by default, but does not affect anything

`sudo nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com ipv4.dns 172.16.27.1
sudo nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com ipv4.dns-search int.contoso.com
sudo nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com ipv4.never-default yes`

> `never-default` should not use remote gateway as default route

And much more interested final touch:

`nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com vpn.data 'ca = /tmp/la.vpn.contoso.com/you/ca.crt, key = /tmp/you.key, dev = tun, cert = /tmp/you.crt, cert-pass-flags = 1, comp-lzo = adaptive, remote = la.vpn.contoso.com:1194, connection-type = tls'`

Afterwards you can control vpn with GUI or use following commands:

`sudo nmcli --ask connection up la.vpn.contoso.com
sudo nmcli connection down la.vpn.contoso.com`